# Sorting HashMap using absolute values of doubles

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I am attempting to sort a hashmap on type `<Integer,Double>` using a `TreeMap` and a `SortedMap` I want to sort on the absolute values of the `Double`s but I also want to retain the sign value (hence not storing as an unsigned `Double`).

Below is the code I am using, however I am not getting the values I expect, presumably due to the use of `hashcode()` can anybody point out how to fix this?

```
Map<Integer,Double> termWeights = new HashMap<Integer,Double>();    
SortedMap sortedData = new TreeMap(new ValueComparer(termWeights));
System.out.println(termWeights);
sortedData.putAll(termWeights);
System.out.println(sortedData);

class ValueComparer implements Comparator {
    private Map _data = null;

    public ValueComparer(Map data) {
        super();
        _data = data;
    }

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        Double e1 = Math.abs((Double) _data.get(o1));
        Double e2 = Math.abs((Double) _data.get(o2));
        int compare = e2.compareTo(e1);
        if (compare == 0) {
            Integer a = o1.hashCode();
            Integer b = o2.hashCode();
            return b.compareTo(a);
        }
        return compare;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the hashCode part supposed to do? Why not just return 0 if the absolute value is equal?

Comment: There are duplicate values in the `Map` returning `0` results in lost information.

Comment: Comparator works fine with unique values, when there are duplicate values (which there are in my case) I need to do a secondary comparison but the absolute value is no longer taken into account (which I need). I want to know how to include the absolute value with `compareTO`

Comment: If it worked I wouldn't have posted. Without the requirement of absolute values of the doubles this comparator is correct. However, as I mentioned, when duplicates occur and `compare == 0` the secondary comparison fails to sort correctly. I know why, due to `hashCode()` ignoring the absolute values of the doubles.

Comment: So, cyclically; how can I avoid this and still sort correctly given duplicates?

Comment: The comparator looks okay. Can you give an example of expected and actual results?

Comment: Unsorted map:
`{0=-1.029545248153297, 1=-2.7105555587851366E-4, 2=-2.7105555587851366E-4, 3=0.0, 4=0.0, 5=0.0, 6=0.0, 7=-2.0897436261984377E-4, 8=-1.305197184270594E-5, 9=-3.331976978545177E-4, 10=-5.291765636407169E-4, 11=0.0, 12=0.0, 13=0.0, 14=0.0, 15=0.0, 17=1.644955871228835, 16=0.0, 19=0.0, 18=0.0, 21=0.0, 20=0.0, 22=0.0}`

Comment: Sorted map: `{17=1.644955871228835, 0=-1.029545248153297, 10=-5.291765636407169E-4, 9=-3.331976978545177E-4, 1=-2.7105555587851366E-4, 2=-2.7105555587851366E-4, 7=-2.0897436261984377E-4, 8=-1.305197184270594E-5, 3=0.0, 4=0.0, 5=0.0, 6=0.0, 11=0.0, 12=0.0, 13=0.0, 14=0.0, 15=0.0, 16=0.0, 18=0.0, 19=0.0, 20=0.0, 21=0.0, 22=0.0}
`

Comment: The first two results are clearly out of order.

Comment: Why? They are the biggest two. the next one is four orders of magnitude smaller. Looks good to me.

Comment: Oh damnit... I need to take a break. I did not correctly read the results.. You are right.

Comment: You should be aware that this "value comparator" trick is evil, very easily broken, and you should do almost anything to avoid it in real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you give an example of expected and actual results?
>
> Sorted map: {17=1.644955871228835, 0=-1.029545248153297, 10=-5.291765636407169E-4, 9=-3.331976978545177E-4, 1=-2.7105555587851366E-4, 2=-2.7105555587851366E-4, 7=-2.0897436261984377E-4, 8=-1.305197184270594E-5, 3=0.0, 4=0.0, 5=0.0, 6=0.0, 11=0.0, 12=0.0, 13=0.0, 14=0.0, 15=0.0, 16=0.0, 18=0.0, 19=0.0, 20=0.0, 21=0.0, 22=0.0}

So what is the problem?

That looks correctly sorted from biggest to smallest.

But I would avoid using hashCode in the tie-break secondary comparator, because you need it to never return the same value for different inputs. In this case, it works, because you are calling it on an Integer, where hashCode just returns the same int. But if you used Long or String keys in your map, it would have collisions. Compare the two keys directly instead.

And finally, you must not change the weights after starting to use the comparator. That will lead to an inconsistent TreeMap.

Comment: I need to sleep is the problem. I did not correctly read my results and notice the orders of magnitude differences. Thanks for the advice.